# Scala remove characters from String following a sequence

Tags: java, string, scala

I have written a sample program to convert xml to json. But I want to remove a characters followed by sequence. How to achieve it.

In below example I want to remove "tns:" in the String if it comes after "<" character.

```
object example {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val xmldata :String = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<tns:createGroup xmlns:tns=\"http://www.emirates.com/schemas/loyalty/customer/group/v1.0/2017/05\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.emirates.com/schemas/loyalty/customer/group/v1.0/2017/05 sample.xsd \">\n  <tns:customerGroup>\n    <tns:groupTypeCode>100</tns:groupTypeCode>\n    <tns:groupTypeDescription>sampleGroup</tns:groupTypeDescription>\n    <tns:groupAccountNumber>100100234</tns:groupAccountNumber>\n    <tns:groupName>sampleName</tns:groupName>\n    <tns:status>open</tns:status>\n    <tns:memberCountThreshold>3</tns:memberCountThreshold>\n    <tns:guestCountThreshold>4</tns:guestCountThreshold>\n    <tns:creatorDetails>\n      <tns:membershipNumber>00800934564</tns:membershipNumber>\n      <tns:mediaCode>400</tns:mediaCode>\n    </tns:creatorDetails>\n    <tns:createdDate>03JUL2017</tns:createdDate>\n    <tns:MilesSummary/>\n  </tns:customerGroup>\n  <tns:error>\n    <tns:errorRecord>noerror</tns:errorRecord>\n  </tns:error>\n</tns:createGroup>\n"
  val loyaltyGroupMessageXML = scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmldata)
  val miles = (loyaltyGroupMessageXML \\ "customerGroup")
  //print(miles)
  val json = toJson(miles)
  //val parsed = parse(json)
  //print(parsed)
  print(pretty(render(json)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to truncate the string after "<tns" or till the end of xml tag ">"?

Comment: yes.... I want only tns: to be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` function

```
xmldata.replace("<tns:", "<")
```

you can use it in your code as

```
val loyaltyGroupMessageXML = scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmldata.replace("<tns:", "<"))
```

You still need to replace the ending `</tns:` to `</`. For that you can do

```
xmldata.replace("<tns:", "<").replace("</tns:", "</")
```

In your code

```
val loyaltyGroupMessageXML = scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmldata.replace("<tns:", "<").replace("</tns:", "</"))
```